# chrome dev tools like UI panel at the bottom of the page UI design

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a CRM sort of application. There are multiple tags at the top of page. Clicking on the tags, should bring up, a chrome dev tools like panel(Ctrl+Shift+I) which will basically contain a table.

I searched the web, but  could not find how to go about creating one. Neiter jQueryUI has any element of that sort, nor the bootstrap library from twitter has something like that.

In case you could throw in some pointers, along those lines. It will be helpful for me.

Thanks!

I am using twitter bootstrap, so that will be helpful.

PS : You can press Ctrl+Shift+I in chrome, to generate the panel, I am talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fairly broad question that potentially has many solutions depending on your exact needs, scenario and skillset. Also, it's always best to post an attempt at the problem to get a better response.

One solution would be to simply hide (display: none;) a sticky div that is attached to the bottom of the window. To show/hide you can use js and either a button/link or try something like http://plugins.jquery.com/project/hotkeys if you want to activate it with a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: oh no its not a broad question, i just want a slider sort of thing, to come up from the bottom, on a particular click. I just want that to happen.

Comment: Here is a very basic implementation of what you are asking: http://jsfiddle.net/mAcBT/

Comment: And you can use the plugin (or something similar) that I referenced above to activate this with a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: any better library/plugin you would suggest for it. Thanks for answering I was unaware of the slide toggle function.

Comment: Glad to be of help. I know there are a few on Github. I would just search for one that fits your needs best.